# How to download Allure report after being generated

Tags: cucumberjs, allure

I am using allure report with cucumberjs. After scripts are executed I am doing allure generate and then open(in my command line) so I am able to see the report in my browser. Also there is a folder crated called allure-report inside which there is a index.html file. The problem is when I close command line and click on this index.html allure report is not loading the data.
My question is how I can download allure report so I can send it to the customer for example?

Answer (score 2):

Allure report is not a static report. So you cannot open it by clicking on index.html.
The workaround is to use 'allure generate ' command to save the website files into a specific folder (files include .json files and index.html), store it in AWS S3 bucket and enable web hosting. 
Then you can send a link of report to a customer.